# How to create list of dictionaries from a single dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I turn a list of dictionaries into a single dictionary?

For example, let's say my initial list is as:

```
Dictionary_list = [{key:value}, {key2:value2}, {key3:value3}]
```

I need the resultant dictionary as:

```
New_dictionary = {key:value, key2:value2, key3:value3}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution would be to create an empty dictionary and update it:

```
>>> my_list = [{'key':'value'}, {'key2':'value2'}, {'key3':'value3'}]
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> for d in my_list: my_dict.update(d)
...
>>> my_dict
{'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```

In general, the [update() method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_update.asp) is mighty useful, typically when you want to create "environments" containing variables from successive dictionaries.

Comment: Because of my basic experience, this answer makes the most sense to me.

Comment: @Ninja_Soup Any of the answers here that gives you the desired result should be making sense to you. You not able to understand them is a different story

Comment: That's what I meant to say. I appreciate you taking time to answer the question, but I am unfamiliar with dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Indeed, different answers for different levels of knowledge, or different needs (speed, etc.). As Donald Knuth pointed out "Let us change our traditional attitude to the construction of programs: Instead of imagining that our main task is to instruct a computer what to do, let us concentrate rather on explaining to human beings what we want a computer to do. " So if more people could understand a piece of code, that could be an advantage.

Answer (score 3):

You may use *dictionary comprehension* to achieve this as:

```
>>> my_list = [{'key':'value'}, {'key2':'value2'}, {'key3':'value3'}]

>>> my_dict = {k: v for item in my_list for k, v in item.items()}
>>> my_dict
{'key3': 'value3', 'key2': 'value2', 'key': 'value'}
```

**Note:** If your initial list of dictionaries will have any "key" present in more than one dictionary, above solution will end up keeping the last "value" of "key" from the initial list.

Answer (score 2):

Functional programming answer:

```
from functools import reduce # depending on version of python you might need this. 

my_list = [{'key':'value'}, {'key2':'value2'}, {'key3':'value3'}]
def func(x,y):
    x.update(y)
    return x
new_dict = reduce(func, my_list)

>>> new_dict
{'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```

One liner:

```
new_dict = reduce(lambda x, y: x.update(y) or x, my_list) # use side effect in lambda
```